# reactjs antd - Progress not animated if using function

Tags: reactjs, antd

I try using `Progress` from `antd`.
I use it in my react function component:

`const [percent, setpercent] = useState(0)`

if I use it directly in my `onclick` event, it works perfectly.

```
<div onClick={(e)=>{setpercent(10)}} >
click me
</div>
```

but if I use function to trigger the change:

```
function handlepercent(v){
  setpercent(v)
}
```

the value in the `Progress` will update, but it is not animated.

Not sure if it is the bug or is there something wrong with the code.

Comment: Add your full code would help a lot

Comment: what does "not animate" mean for you ?

Answer (score 1):

please check the code bellow

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-estrela-liz522?file=/src/App.js

```
import { Progress } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [percent, setpercent] = useState(0);

  function handlepercent(v) {
    setpercent(v);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Progress percent={percent} />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handlepercent(50)}>
        50%
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setpercent(100)}>
        100%
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```